# Assert if Func is called with required parameters

Tags: c#, nunit

```
 public class ClassUnderTest
    {
        void Process(Func<string, bool> doSomething)
        {
            //other code
            doSomething("123");
        }
    }
```

How do I assert that **doSomething** is called with parameter **123**?

Comment: Pass your own Func delegate which has an assert for parameter 123 ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Make the comment as an answer please for me to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as that. Just create a delegate which does the assertion and pass it to the `Process` method.

For example:

```
[Test]
public void SomeTestCase()
{
    ClassUnderTest sut = new ClassUnderTest();
    Func<string, bool> func = (param)=> 
    {
        Assert.That(param, Is.EqualTo("123"));
        return true;//or whatever
    };

    sut.Process(func);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example Rhino Mocks:

```
someObject.AssertWasCalled(x => x.doSomething("123"));
```

Check this: https://hibernatingrhinos.com/Oss/rhino-mocks/learn/Usage/assert-that-a-method-is-called-with-a-value-in-expected-state

Comment: What is the type of someObject? Should I create a sample class that has doSomething method?

Comment: I think that you have a code similar to this: `var cut = new ClassUnderTest(); var some = new SomeObject(); cut.Process(some.DoSomething);` So in your test you should create SomeObject, pass it to ClassUnderTest and after that invoke some.AssertWasCalled(x => x.DoSomething("123"))